# How do you extract vertices from a numpy-stl mesh?

Tags: stl, numpy-stl

I am trying to use numpy-stl to extract the vertices from an stl model to use for coherent point drift registration. How do you go about extracting the vertices? I understand how to create a mesh from a list of vertices and faces, but not how to go backwards.

I've tried: Creating a new mesh from vertices and faces. Importing created mesh.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a .stl file of a cuboid with length 100, width 200, height 300.

```
from stl import mesh
import numpy as np

cuboid = mesh.Mesh.from_file("./cuboid.stl")
points = np.around(np.unique(cuboid.vectors.reshape([cuboid.vectors.size/3, 3]), axis=0),2)
print "Points are", points.tolist()
```

Output:

```
Points are [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 300.0], [0.0, 200.0, 0.0], [0.0, 200.0, 300.0], [100.0, 0.0, 0.0], [100.0, 0.0, 300.0], [100.0, 200.0, 0.0], [100.0, 200.0, 300.0]]
```

Comment: You need to edit the following to work: `int(cuboid.vectors.size/3)`